# Equaity of two norms of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to prove that if A is a $n \times k $ matrix and $A^H$ the hermitian matrix of A,

$||A||_2=||A^H||_2$.

Where $||A||_2=\sup\{ ||Ax||: ||x||\leq 1\}$ and $|| \cdot ||$ is the euclidean nrmm of a vector.

Any hint ?

Comment: For *vectors*, $\|x\|_2 = \sup_{\|y\|_2\leq 1} x^Ty$. This is useful here.

Comment: So I can write $ ||Ax||=\sup_{||y||_2 \leq 1} x^H A^H y $?

Comment: Yes, I would definitely do that. And if you figure out the rest, post the answer, so you get credit for both!

Comment: And then I can conclude because $\sup_{||y||_2 \leq 1} x^H A^H y=||A^H x|| $?

Comment: You should put $x^HA^Hy$ to absolute value (in case it might be complex).

Answer (score 0):

The usual proof, as I've seen it: noting that $A^HA$ and $AA^H$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues, we have
$$
\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \sqrt{x^HA^HAx} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^HA)} = s_1(A) = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(AA^H)}
 = \|A^H\|_2
$$